# Traçar Rotas - Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estou com dificuldade em traçar rota.

Tenho 2 inputs text, com a função de auto completar do google.

Quando o usuário marca o segundo input. O mapa já traça a rota entre os dois pontos.

Porem quero fazer uma modificação, e estou com problemas.

Quero trocar o segundo ponto, por vários radios button.

Então o usuário vai marcar o radio button, e quando digitar a localização no input text, vai traçar a rota automaticamente.

Aqui esta a parte do código onde ele faz o auto completar do campo, e o traçar rota:

```
origin_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        var place = origin_autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
            window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
            return;
        }
        expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);

        // If the place has a geometry, store its place ID and route if we have
        // the other place ID
        origin_place_id = place.place_id;
        route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode, directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    });

    destination_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        var place = destination_autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
            window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
            return;
        }
        expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);

        // If the place has a geometry, store its place ID and route if we have
        // the other place ID
        destination_place_id = place.place_id;
        route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode, directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    });

    function route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        if (!origin_place_id || !destination_place_id) {
            return;
        }
        directionsService.route({
            origin: {'placeId': origin_place_id},
            destination: {'placeId': destination_place_id}, travelMode: travel_mode
        }, function(response, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            } else {
                window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
        });
    }
```

Eu pego a posição do radio button assim:

```
positionMarkerSelected = markersArray[indiceAux].getPosition();
```

E tentei substituir direto na função que traça a rota:

```
directionsService.route({
                origin: {'placeId': origin_place_id},
                destination: positionMarkerSelected ,   travelMode: travel_mode
            }
```

Porem não funciona,  alguém sabe como poderia resolver isso ?